# If I have more than one item in a column of a text file then how can I import it in SQL using python?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

```
ISBN    BOOK             Author                                Genre
123456 Child dreams     John and Helda                        Educational, emotional
435678  Emotions         Dr. Fedrick Patrins and Veela manok   Educational, emotional, creative, awareness
```

I am able to load ISBN and Book in one table:(text file is separated by tab)

```
with open('file path') as xyz:
    read=csv.reader(xyz, delimiter='\t')
    total_books = iter(read)`enter code here`
    next(total_books)
 for row in total_books:
      cursor.execute"INSERT INTO book_titles VALUES (%s, %s)", (row[0], row[1]))
                db.commit()
```

But, what if column has more than one values like in Author and Genre

Comment: Are you saying in the first row that Educational, emotional are separated by a comma and a tab? If so then it's not a tab separated file.

Comment: What I mean is that columns are tab separated  i.e ISBN, Book, Author, Genre are tab separated

Answer (score 0):

An example of a normalized schema:

```
books
book_id ISBN    TITLE           
      1 123456  Child dreams    
      2 435678  Emotions        

authors                    
author_id name
       11 John 
       12 Helda                     
       13 Dr. Fedrick Patrins 
       14 Veela Manok   

genres
genre_id genre
     101 educational
     102 emotional
     103 creative
     104 awareness

book_author
id book_id author_id
1        1 11
2        1 12
3        2 13
4        2 14

book_genre
book_id genre_id
      1 101
      1 102
      2 101
      2 102
      2 103
      2 104
```